# System gives FileNotFound Error although file exists (Nim)

Tags: git-bash, file-not-found

So I started to learn Nim and while it is technically going fine, I have a problem with compiling and running my code.
Every time I try to run a .nim file in BASH (Nim c -r filename.nim) or VS Code (F6) (basically whatever I use) gives me this:
[image]

(the red part just means the system could not find the file)

[image]

Interestingly, if I try to run it with ./filname.nim (just ./filname does nothing as you see) it runs, but this would make it very complicated because I had to do all testing outside of VS Code this way.

I have a virgin installation and the code just echo "Hello World" and I already tried reinstalling.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is the path to gcc.exe has a trailing slash (gcc.exe) which makes the system look for some directory under gcc.exe which of course does not exist. I just need to manually change it in the environment variables